# Azure kit vs Simple ASP.Net webform application

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, web-deployment, cloud-hosting

Working on `Flexible computing`, meanz single code for multiple customers.
 I have two choices.

- we will use `ASP.Net webform` application and deploy it on any `ASP.NET hosting site`.
- second choice is we will go on cloud and develop a SaaS product.

we want to work on .NET platform. so there's some question that i want to ask you.

1. If we work on cloud, `AZURE` kit is available for development. but i have read that you can also deploy your ASP.NET appliaction(webform) on Azure also. 

   So, i want to ask you **the difference between the project i.e. completed on AZURE using kit and `SQL AZURE` , and the project completed on ASP.NET webforms and deployed on AZURE.**

   Please tell me the pros and cons briefly.
2. If we use `AZURE` then we need `SQL AZURE`, So are there many difference between `SQL` and `AZURE SQL`.
   Do i need to learn `SQL Azure`. I know `SQL Server`
3. I am also worried about the sessionless environment in Azure.
4. Is there any toolkit, Guide, Tutorial links that can help in our project and you know about it please share.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure what you mean by `Azure Kit` but they are several ways to deploy your application on windows azure.

You can spin off a VM and deploy like you would on a dedicated server or you can deploy as a cloud service (using a web role).

They currently support deploying websites (a bit different from cloud services) and these websites are deployed in a managed VM (managed by them).

If you are deploying as a cloud service using a web role, you can deploy a regular asp.net web forms app with no changes whatsoever.

SQL Azure is very similar to Sql Server, when i deployed, i didn't make any sql azure specific changes.

On the reliability of the sessions, you can use a state server instead of InProc.
So your sessions will be stored inside a sql server instance and can be accessed by multiple web roles.

On the subject of guides you can check out [the cloud service link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/) or the [web sites option](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/)